# Angular 7: NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBarConfig

Tags: angular, angular-material

In our project we use `Angular 7` and `Angular Material`. Everything is fine under `Google Chrome` but under `Internet Explorer 11`, when the app is run with `--aot` flag, we receive the following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatSnackBarContainer -> MatSnackBarConfig]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatSnackBarContainer -> MatSnackBarConfig]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBarConfig!
```

The `Material` modules are imported in a separate file as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ...
  MatSnackBarModule,
  ...
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ...
    MatSnackBarModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class MyMaterialModule { }
```

Please note: the app works just fine under `Google Chrome`!
Any ideas? Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: You can look this relevant:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8375

Comment: Is it because you didn’t include the necessary polyfills for IE browsers? (You have to uncomment and install them manually in your polyfill file.)

Comment: @GermanBurgardt The issue you’ve linked is not relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the service you are trying to use has not been provided in your @NgModule.

To use the `MatDialog` service, you will need to go to your module file and add `MatSnackBarModule` to the array of imports:

```
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatSnackBarModule]
})
export class MyMaterialModule {}
```

Comment: No idea what you are saying. I DO import the `MatSnackBarModule` module.

Comment: yes, in a separate module, I've imported and then exported all Material modules. Please note that everything works just fine under Chrome.